# generated jar file problem switching Windows/Linux OS

Tags: java, windows, linux, eclipse, jar

I encountered a strange situation and I'm struggling myself, trying to understand which is the problem.

I developed a Java application under Eclipse using Swing and jdbc.
I exported an executable jar file, created using Eclipse under Windows.

When I execute the exported file under Linux, everything is working fine, (both the gui and the database access) except that the JDialogs that sometimes are displayed, are not showing anymore in Linux. 
If I generate the jar again, under Linux, (without modifying anything in the source code) JDialogs begin to work again.

What's the reason for this?
It seems that the problem isn't related to my source code, so do I have always to generate again an executable jar for every different operating system?
And again, if it is a problem related to the jar building process, why the only problem occurs with JDialogs?

I hope to be clear

thanks in advance to all

Comment: What kind of JDK are you using on Linux? I use sun-jdk on both Windows and Ubuntu because I've had some problems with the open-jdk shipped with Ubuntu.

Comment: @zeropage: I'm using sun-jdk-6 both on windows and linux

Comment: Just to check, see if eclipse actually uses the sun-jdk and not another one.

Comment: Try to force different look & feel settings to see if it is a Swing->GTK problem. http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html

Answer (score 2):

Of course you don't have to build on every platform. The idea is to make it once, run everywhere. Are you using the same versions of JDK/JRE on the Windows and Linux machines? Versions of other tools, e.g. Eclipse, Ant?

Comment: yes I'm using the same jdk/jre version. I'm not currently using Ant.

Comment: I assume you are using the exact same project settings and files between the Windows and Linux Eclipse builds. To eliminate other possible differences, try using "Enable project specific settings" in Eclipse under the "Java Compiler" project properties.

Comment: Note that there are subtle differences between the incremental compiler used in Eclipse vs the javac compiler. It might help to try doing a full rebuild by disabling "Build Automatically", then doing "Clean" and "Build Project".

Answer (score 1):

There are some Components in java swing that have bugs and may not be platform independant.

Perhaps JDialog is one of those bugs.